# Numpy: create upper triangular matrix by repeating sequence adding pad

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

What is the most efficient way of creating an upper triangular matrix from a given sequence as follows:

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

for **any** sequence

Comment: From linked one's accepted answer, for `sliding_windows`, edit `b = np.concatenate((p,a))` and `return strided(b[W-1:], shape=(W,len(a)), strides=(-s,s))`.

Comment: Or with existing one `sliding_windows(a,len(a))[:,:len(a)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.triu` is what you are looking for: it take an `array` as parameter and returns an upper triangular matrix ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)):

```
import numpy as np

seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

res = np.triu(seq)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 2 3 4 5]
 [0 0 3 4 5]
 [0 0 0 4 5]
 [0 0 0 0 5]]
```

Comment: This is not what the question asks to generate.